# Is it possible to cross-compile an already compiled file? ARM Cortex M4

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, stm32

I'm working on a project where I have to port a compiled file for x86 architecture to a STM32F401RE, which has an ARM Cortex M4 processor. 
Is it possible to cross-compile the already compiled file? I don't have access to the c code, since the output is given by a parser that directly translate the higher level language to the executable file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to say it's not possible. Even if you somehow managed to translate all x86 instructions to ARM instructions. An executable compiled for x86 from a higher level language most definitely relies on an operating system for loading, memory access, IO etc. You will not have such an OS on a Cortex M4.

Comment: Automagically? No. It's feasible? Depending on what the appliecation relies on, probably yes. It's the better solution? Probably it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @Damiano Yes. Jason Turner has tried to make an x86 to 6502 translator, but it's extremely limiting to what you can do in your code. He ended up compiling to AVR and then translating to 6502, as those are much more similar in terms of instructions/registers.

Comment: It might be possible in some universe, but probably not this one.  I think the intent of this answer is correct.